Limit of a recursively-defined sequence
What is the limit of the sequence defined as
$$
(x)_{ n\geq 0},\qquad x_0 = 1,\quad
x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \frac{2}{x_{n}}\ ?.
$$
Since it's an increasing sequence, I suppose it is also divergent with a limit of $\infty$, but I don't know how to rigorously prove it.
$$
\mbox{Then, what is the limit of}\quad {x_{n} \over n^{1/2}}\ ?.
$$
I don't have the intuition of how I should even approach this kind of limit problem. If you could give me some hints or point me out to resources I would much appreciate $\mbox{it !.}$

Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? What do you usualy do with those problems?

I have tried to analyze its monotony, and to determine whether the limit exists and if it converges, I know the limit exists since the sequence is well defined over all R, but I am not sure how to test for convergence. I can handle well linear recursions, but I get stuck in these situations.

Assume that the limit exists (i.e., is finite).  Would this result in a contradiction?

Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=L<\infty$. Then take limit on both sides of the recurrence relation and see what happens.

I tried doing that, and I do, indeed, get a contradiction, since L would need to be $\infty$ to satisfy the equation.

Then, what is the question? An increasing sequence either diverges to $+\infty$ or converges. As the latter is impossible, it must diverge.

Thank you for helping me clarify this rigorously. Could you also give me a hint about the second question, the limit of $x_n/\sqrt n$?

Follow a similar approach: probably, from some point onwards, the sequence will be decreasing.

Thank you, I will try.

For the first part, yes, the sequence is clearly increasing. Assume it's bounded by some $L<\infty$, and reach a contradiction by looking at what $x_{n+1} \geq x_n + \frac2L$ says about something like $x_{L^2}$.
For the second part, I would insetad look at the sequence $y_n = x_n^2$, and trying to find a limit value for $\frac{y_n}n$ (because it just looks a lot easier not to have to deal with the square root). Try to massage the original recurrence relation into one that says something about $y_{n+1}$ in terms of $y_n$, and go from there.

Thank you! I will look into it
